# Unable to connect Database Postgres(9.2) with error File "base/16384/PG_VERSION" is missing

Tags: postgresql

> Could not create connection; - nested throwable:
>   (org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: "base/16 384" is not a
>   valid data directory   Detail: File "base/16384/PG_VERSION" is
>   missing.); - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossRe
>   sourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable:
>   (org.postgresql.util.PSQLException : FATAL: "base/16384" is not a
>   valid data directory   Detail: File "base/16384/PG_VERSION" is
>   missing.))

`base/16384/` in this folder there is no files like

```
pg_filenode.map
pg_internal.init
PG_VERSION
```

I don't know how they deleted.

Here I can copy paste the PG_VERSION file. How can I get remaining files?

Answer (score 0):

It is looking like terrible broken PostgreSQL database. If you have a backup, restore from backup.

Comment: Pavel Stehule Thanks for your reply, I don't have any back up, what is the purpose of pg_filenode.map, pg_internal.init files?. And at what scenario we will loose these files?.

Comment: I don't know what is "pg_internal.init" - it is related to some unsupported PostgreSQL releases. pg_filenode.map translates tables oid to filename. And what can be wrong? some IO fault, some antivir fault, some human error, some wrong migration, .. hard to say.